# java.lang.IllegalStateException error in Android Sqlite3 "group by" clause

Tags: android, sqlite, group-by, cursor

This is my query in sqlite3 by adb shell:

```
sqlite> SELECT round FROM prizes GROUP BY round;
100-7
```

However, I got a problem when translating it into Java code:

```
LinkedList<String> result = new LinkedList<String>();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT round FROM prizes GROUP BY round", null);
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        result.add(cursor.getString(1));
    } while (cursor.moveToLast());
}
if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed())
    cursor.close();

return (String[]) result.toArray();
```

When I run this code, I got an error:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10540): java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col 1 failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have only 1 column returned form your query (`round`) and the index is zero-based

See the doc about [getString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString%28int%29)

> Returns the value of the requested column as a String. The result and
>   whether this method throws an exception when the column value is null
>   or the column type is not a string type is implementation-defined.
>   Parameters
>
> **columnIndex**   the zero-based index of the target column.

The below should work:

```
  result.add(cursor.getString(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be `cursor.getString(0)` since its a 0-based index.